# System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Any suggestion on how to capture the exact issue? It is happening on the master page but unable to find the exact issue.

Error captured:

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'. ---> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ASP.views_shared_login_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0() at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func) at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Base controller Method

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
    {
        ErrorHandler.HandleError(controllerName, "", filterContext.Exception, "", memberName: actionName);
    }
    else
    {
    
        int lineNumber = -1;
        string fieldName = "<unknown>";
        try
        {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(filterContext.Exception, true);
        StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
        lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
        fieldName = stackFrame.GetFileName();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        RequestUrl = filterContext.HttpContext?.Request?.Url,
        ParentActionViewContext = filterContext.ParentActionViewContext?.ToString(),
        Result = filterContext.Result?.ToString(),
        FieldName = fieldName,
        LineNumber = lineNumber
    });
    ErrorHandler.HandleError(this, SessionHelper.UserId.ToString(), filterContext.Exception, message);
}
    base.OnException(filterContext);
```

}